# AWS Cognito with Serverless Local Environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, local, amazon-cognito, serverless

This is an issue we found on [Github](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/issues/487) and are having the same issue:

> We're using serverless and serverless-offline to run lambda locally.
>   We have a local DynamoDB implementation. For Cognito however,
>   serverless-offline mocks the authenticated user and cognitoIdentityId.
>   The mocked user has permission to invoke the lambda but not to pass in
>   the cognitoIdentityId to match what we save in DynamoDB for a user.
>
> 1. This may be a serverless-offline problem, and there may be other,
>      better solutions.
> 2. Or there may be a way to run Cognito locally.
> 3. Or we can hit Cognito from our local. But we don't know how to do this.
>
> tldr; I'm not sure what the best practice is around developing labmdas
>   locally when using Cognito with authorizer: aws_iam

Comment: Assuming this is for testing purposes, I prefer to mock AWS calls locally, so I would pass in some fake identity in and tailor the test around it (like making sure it's in local dynamodb or even mock the dynamodb part) and for integration testing I believe you should target real resources and not use serverless-offline at all.

Answer (score 2):

Though this may or may not help with your problem here's how to mock Cognito while running locally.

Every AWS service accepts a configuration. In this configuration you can pass an `endpoint` parameter. You can pass a local server to this config and mock your desired response for every aws service.

```
export const getIdentityProvider = () => new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  endpoint: process.env.IS_TEST ? 'http://localhost:5001' : null
})
```

AWS services perform a POST call with the date you are sending as the body and the function name as part of the `x=amz-target` header. For example the `AdminGetUser` Cognito call has the header: `'x-amz-target': 'AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.AdminGetUser'`

You can create a basic server to handle this like this:

```
import http from 'http'
const getBody = async request => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let body = ''
    request.on('data', (data) => {
      body += data
    })
    request.on('end', () => {
      resolve(JSON.parse(body))
    })
  })
}

const server = http.createServer(async (req, res) => {
  const body = await getBody(req)
  const route = req.headers['x-amz-target']

  let response
  const status = 200

  switch (route) {
    case 'AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.AdminGetUser':
      response = { foo: 'bar' }
      break
  }

  res.writeHead(response ? status : 404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' })
  res.write(response || 'No route found')
  res.end()
})
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 5001, 'localhost', () => {
  console.log(`Proxy server listening on port http://${server.address().address}:${server.address().port}`)
})
```

In order to know what to return I recommend doing some unit tests and capturing the response with [nock](https://github.com/nock/nock). You can then extract the response body and use that in your mock server.